# Info Windows in Google map doesn't show pictures- android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api

I've been trying to show some info whith info windows -in my app which uses google map- with InfoWindowAdapter but it just does'nt show any pictures so whats the problem?

here's my code for it

```
public class findonmap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Bundle recevier=getIntent().getExtras();
    float a=recevier.getFloat("x");
    float b=recevier.getFloat("y");

    LatLng mycordinate = new LatLng(a,b);


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mycordinate).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                    fromResource(R.drawable.marker2)));

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
           // ConstraintLayout layout=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.indo)
            View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info,null);
            return view;
        }
    });
    int zoomLevel = 4; //This goes up to 21
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mycordinate, zoomLevel));

}}
```

Comment: what is the problem you're facing in displaying picture??

Comment: simply it doesnt show any picture

Comment: share your code where you're setting image